# How Can I sort ITunes store API entity=song by popularity?

Tags: ios, itunes-store, itunes-sdk

I don't see the popularity field in the song entity json, am I able to sort by it?

something like that:

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=211192863&entity=song&sort=popular

it seems like a pretty basic stuff, it would be a shame of apple not having it

Answer (score 1):

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=15/json
```

just take a link from

http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss

and replace xml with json

Comment: This doesnt give me the exact popularity. Its on a 0-1 scale.

Comment: This does not change sorting in the method cited by "The Poet", nor a lookup parameter.